# fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file) preventing image upload due to parameter not being type "Blob"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, crud, filereader

I'm trying to upload a picture for use inside a modal, which does properly display the default assigned image but when updated will cause a 405 error. I've narrowed down the culprit inside this update function:

```
function update()
{

var reader = new FileReader();
var file = $('#fileUpload')[0].files[0];
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

reader.onload = function (readerEvt)
{
    //get binary data then convert to encoded string
    var binaryString = reader.result;
    var encodedString = btoa(binaryString);

    //normal update fields
    emp = new Object();
    emp.Title = $("#TextBoxTitle").val();
    emp.Firstname = $("#TextBoxFirstname").val();
    emp.Lastname = $("#TextBoxLastname").val();
    emp.Phoneno = $("#TextBoxPhone").val();
    emp.Email = $("#TextBoxEmail").val();
    emp.StaffPicture64 = encodedString;
    emp.Id = localStorage.getItem("Id");
    emp.DepartmentId = localStorage.getItem("DepartmentId");
    emp.Version = localStorage.getItem("Version");
}
ajaxCall("Put", "api/employees", emp)
    .done(function (data) {
        $("#myModal").modal("hide");
        getAll(data);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        errorRoutine(jqXHR);
    });
return false; 
}
```

to this block of code:

```
 var reader = new FileReader();
var file = $('#fileUpload')[0].files[0];
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

specifically the reader.readAsBinaryString(file); line. When a breakpoint is set here, I get returned this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.(…)

This confuses me greatly, as I've directly copied this file upload section from a working example of such I made very recently. I don't understand why one would work perfectly and another would have return an error when they are both using no external input except for the '#fileUpload' tag, which I definitely have in the .html page:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 text-left">
   <input id="fileUpload" type="file" />
 </div>
```

Why is this happening? Have I incorrectly referenced my fileUpload tag?

Comment: Normally this error happens if you have not selected any files and try to get the file from the _file element_. So if you are sure that you have selected a file to upload and are getting this error, then maybe you have more than **one** element in your document with the id of `fileUpload`, please check your source for this issue

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the FileReader and you shouldn't post it as json if that is what you are doing...

When uploading files you have to use multipart upload and by doing so you have to use `FormData`

```
function update() {

  var file = $('#fileUpload')[0].files[0]
  var fd = new FormData

  fd.append('Title', $('#TextBoxTitle').val())
  fd.append('Firstname', $('#TextBoxFirstname').val())
  fd.append('Lastname', $('#TextBoxLastname').val())
  fd.append('Phoneno', $('#TextBoxPhone').val())
  fd.append('Email', $('#TextBoxEmail').val())
  fd.append('StaffPicture64', file)
  fd.append('Id', localStorage.getItem('Id'))
  fd.append('DepartmentId', localStorage.getItem('DepartmentId'))
  fd.append('Version', localStorage.getItem('Version'))

  fetch('api/employees', {method: 'PUT', body: fd})
  .then(function (res) {
    if (res.ok) {
      $('#myModal').modal('hide')
      getAll(res)
    } else {
      errorRoutine(res)
    }
  })
}
```